# Resource error pease tell me how to solve

Tags: android, android-studio

Android resource linking failed

> C:\Users\Afraz\Desktop\Summaira
>   FYP\PHMS\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2103:
>   error: resource android:attr/foregroundInsidePadding is private.
>   C:\Users\Afraz\Desktop\Summaira
>   FYP\PHMS\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2433:
>   error: resource android:attr/popupPromptView is private. error: failed
>   linking references.

Comment: share your `values.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use `android:attr/foregroundInsidePadding` and `android:attr/popupPromptView`. They would be `public` if they were meant to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I have coincided this error couple of times before so I recommend you to delete your .idea file and then apply invalidate cashes and restart in AS. You will get rid of this error after that